# python pack integer as hex byte

Tags: python, python-3.x

I thought this would be simple, but spent quite some time trying to figure it out.

I want to convert an integer into a byte string, and display in **hex format**. But I seem to get the ascii representation? Specifically, for int value of `122`.

```
from struct import *
pack("B",122) #this returns b'z', what i need is 'b\x7A'
pack("B",255) #this returns b'\xff', which is fine.
```

I know in python 2.x you can use something like `chr()` but not in python 3, which is what I have. Ideally the solution would work in both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use codecs or string encoding

```
codecs.encode(pack("B",122),"hex")
```

or

```
a = pack("B",122)
a.encode("hex")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting the results you desire, and that whatever you are using to look at your results is causing the confusion.  Try running this code:

```
from struct import *
x = pack("B",122)
assert 123 == x[0] + 1
```

You will discover that it works as expected and does not assert.

Comment: I think you could be correct, but the problem is that because its showing up as b'x\00z' instead of b'\x7A', when i go to do a calculation for a checksum fon this value, it gives the wrong answer.